# Changing colour of geom_dotplot points without messing up alignment

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to have my boxplots coloured like the levels of a factor (called "organ" in my code), but not the individual data points (shown as dots).

In the code below, when I use `aes(fill=organ)` in `geom_dotplot`, the data points are aligned like I want them, but coloured like the levels of the factor "organ". [Here's the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHvm1.jpg)

[image]

In the second code, I use `fill="black"` in `geom_dotplot`, which makes the points black as I want them, but it also misaligns them (see [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxaZO.jpg)).

[image]

Is there any way to have my points black but also aligned to the boxplots?

Data points aligned, but not coloured black ([first plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHvm1.jpg)):

```
ggplot(tum_sub_ilc1s, aes(x=group, y=freq, fill=organ)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge2(preserve="single"), color="black") + 
  scale_fill_grey(start=0.4, end=0.8, name="Organ", labels=c("1", "2")) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill=organ), stackdir='center', binaxis='y', dotsize=0.5, 
    position=position_dodge(0.8))
```

Data points coloured black (as I wante them), but misaligned ([second plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxaZO.jpg)):

```
ggplot(tum_sub_ilc1s, aes(x=group, y=freq, fill=organ)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge2(preserve="single"), color="black") +    
  scale_fill_grey(start=0.4, end=0.8, name="Organ", labels=c("1", "2")) + 
  geom_dotplot(fill="black", stackdir='center', binaxis='y', dotsize=0.5, 
    position=position_dodge(0.8))
```

Comment: I can't be sure without any data to test, but likely the `fill` inside the `aes()` was doubling implicitly as a `group`, so to re-align the points, you would have to add `aes(group = organ)` to the `geom_dotplot()` of your second plot.

Comment: Hi @teunbrand, thanks for your reply. My `group` factor has 7 levels (YC, AMC, etc.), whereas my `organ` factor has 2 levels (1, 2), so adding `group=group` or `group=organ` to `geom_dotplot()` did not solve the issue. I managed to fix it by adding `aes(group=group:organ)` to `geom_dotplot()`, which made my points align to all my 10 boxplots.